# jquery serializearray - how to remove 3 elements or how to make them different

Tags: jquery, sql, serialization

I'm using the serializearray with success, but now I need to make a trick.

How can I build this array, but defining that some inputs must have a specific class, so I can make diferent sql queryes based on that?

this is what I'm now using

```
$.each($("form[name='admin']").serializeArray(), function(i, campo)
```

I need it like that, but also need to add something to compare, per example

```
if(something) {
    $sql_query = 'select * from admin';
} else {
    $sql = 'select * from teste';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and filter the collection based on your own requirements, then call serialize.

```
$('#myForm :input').map(function(i,e){
  // test against e, return the object if it's
  // a good fit, otherwise return null
  var $e = $(e);
  return ($e.hasClass('foo') ? $e : null);
}).searializeArray();
```

Comment: thanks for reply, my form has multiple elements, input, check boxes, selectors, and I nedd to post everything, but in server side, on php I need to be able to make choices based on something

Comment: ok, manage in a different way, but this may not be the most elegant way, I add another form, on submit, jquery posts both form values with different variables and it's done. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following. Chances are you don't need to use `.serializeArray` because you want to pass the values through a POST request:

```
var postString = $('form[name='admin'] input.classToFind').serialize();
```

Comment: ok, manage in a different way, but this may not be the most elegant way, I add another form, on submit, jquery posts both form values with different variables and it's done. Thanks for help